# glsl es 2.0 discard and depth buffer

Tags: opengl-es, depth-buffer

OpenGL ES 2.0 can't write to Depth Buffer, since it doesn't have `gl_FragDepth`, but if I do `discard` - will it affect Depth Buffer (I mean, not overwrite it with CURRENT `gl_FragCoord.z`, but leave as is)?

Something like this:

```
void main() {
   if (sin(x) > 0.5 ){
      discard;
   } else {
      gl_FragColor = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   }
}
```

I expect to get holes in Depth Buffer, in `discard` cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement saying "OpenGL ES 2.0 can't write to Depth Buffer" is somewhat misleading. It will write to the depth buffer, as long as there is a depth buffer in the current framebuffer, and depth buffer writes are enabled.

Not having a writable `gl_FragDepth` variable in the fragment shader means that you can't **modify** the depth value in the fragment shader. It's alway the incoming depth value that is written to the depth buffer.

If you `discard` a fragment, neither the color nor the depth value is written. So yes, if you discard a fragment, the depth buffer will not be modified for that fragment.